# Mysterious padding around header

Tags: css

I have tested this in Google Chrome, IE, as well as Firefox and I am getting the strangest bug. I have made a horizontal list, and despite setting padding and margins to 0, I am still getting padding above and to the left of it.

It can be seen here:

http://dev.mcmodcenter.net/

CSS Source:
http://pastebin.com/TJ6k1KwS

Comment: I'm not really sure which padding you're talking about.  I don't see what's wrong.  Is it around header or the body?

Comment: All of it, actually. There was a pretty noticeable gap between every element and the edge of the window.

Comment: Then do what BoltClock said.  Set body's margin and padding to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are `body` margins, which all browsers add by default.

You need to remove them from within your stylesheet, like so:

```
body {
    background: url('./bg.png');
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `header` div is fine.

You haven't set the margin on `body`, which gives you a default value (8px on my browser).

Set body's margin to 0 and you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

It is wise to always use a CSS reset style sheet. You can find one here => http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/.